# Should I install both j2EE and J2SE

Tags: glassfish, java

I just installed J2EE. Det version that come bundled with a JDK. Is there any reason for me to install Java SE as well?

I need to run Java SE programs, but the J2EE bundled java runtime should work fine.

The reason I ask is because most documentation says you have to install both, but other than the fact that J2EE does not add java.exe to PATH, I see not reason to do so.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be very confusing.

J2SE is usually referred to as the "JDK". You can also install the J2EE libraries on top of the JDK so that you can develop J2EE apps. Also, you can install a J2EE *server* (like JBoss) to run J2EE apps.

Either way, you probably have enough Java libraries installed on your machine to do practically anything you would want with Java. There are a few reasons though for installing an additional JDK or JRE:

- If you want to use applets in web sites, then make sure that your installed version is working with your preferred browser. If not, then simply install the latest JRE.
- If you want to use a library that requires a different version of the JRE or JDK, then you will need to install that. The good news is that you can install a bunch of different versions of the JDK on any OS and it will work well.

HTH!